# Asp.Net core realtime database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, real-time-updates

Is there an solution to make a Asp.Net core backend "real time"?
What i mean on realtime is, for example an angular framework app conects to the backend, and when someone updates something in the database it notifies the connected frontend about it.

Like how the firebase realtime database/firestore works.

Comment: uhh, i just found: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr
Which seem what i am looking for. 
However i leave the topic open as of now, for experiences, discussions.

Comment: This is not a forum for discussions about experiences. Please accept the answer by @abo before we can close the question for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My tip would also be SignalR in combination with websockets. On this page you will find helpful codes samples: [Introduction to ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

On these two pages you will find an overview of how SignalR is structured. A practical example can be found here: [Hands On Lab: Real-Time Web Applications with SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr)